# How to instantly close all async running tasks

Tags: python, loops, websocket, python-asyncio

I can't figure out how I can get out of an async loop. I have some code that has to run until I get all the data I want.

```
async def subscribe(url, subs):
    ws_responses = []
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        for sub in subs:
            sub_str = json.dumps(sub)
            await websocket.send(sub_str)
        while len(ws_responses) <= len(subs):
            rsp = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
            if 'data' in rsp:
                ws_responses.append(rsp['data']['s'])
            if len(ws_responses) == len(subs):
                break
        return ws_responses

def main():
    market_url = 'wss://stream.bybit.com/spot/quote/ws/v2'
    market_subs = [{
        "topic": "depth",
        "event": "sub",
        "params": {
            "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
        }}
    ]
    while True:
        try:
            response = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
                subscribe(market_url, market_subs))
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            print('websocket connection error. reconnect rightnow')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

this action is done in a second, but the data is not printed until 40 seconds later. I need to know how to end all async processes instantly. I need to return data, because the main function will be used in another program

I tried closing the connection in subscribe `websocket.close()`, but it did not change anything.also i tried creating `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` after `loop.create_task(subcribe(market_url, market_subs))` and `loop.close()`, but it also didn't help me.

Comment: You are already returning the data as soon as the subscribe task is finished.  How do you know that the action is done in a second if nothing prints for 40 seconds?

Comment: I added `start = datetime.now()` at the beginning of the subscribe function and output `print(datetime.now() - start)` when the while loop was over. it took a second.

Comment: You put the `print(datetime.now() - start)` where, exactly?  The `subscribe` function will not return until the `async with` block exits.  You might try putting print in two places inside that function: (1) after the while loop but inside the async with block.  Then un-indent the return statement to move it outside the async with block, and (2) put a print statement right in front of the return.  Then you will know exactly how long the subscribe function takes.  You might also put a print statement inside main, just before the return.

Comment: In the first case the while loop completes in a second, but if you put return outside the subscribe, it takes 30 seconds. then how do I instantly exit async with?

Comment: Once again I do not understand.  "subscribe" is the function itself, so what do you mean by putting "return outside subscribe?".  It is perhaps impossible to return instantly from the inside of the with: block, since before the block can exit it will execute a function `__aexit__`, which may take time.  You need to understand why websockets.connect takes so long to terminate - maybe it has to close open connections?  You could move the opening of the connection to a higher level, and pass the websocket object down the chain of function calls.